# How to output content to a page

Tags: forms

I have a form on my page that is being submitted. I am implementing `hook_form_submit` and within that function I have a search algorithm that processes the entered data and returns a result. I would like to display that result on the page underneath the search box. For debugging purposes so far I've simply used `drupal_set_message()` but this is no permanent solution.
I am new to Drupal module development so I am unsure how to go about this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I posted to quickly, my apologies.

After re-reading your post, I would advise you to work with an AJAX callback that returns te search results.

First of all you need to create a form api implementation that holds the ajax callback

```
$form['search']['client'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('Search Client'),
'#description' => t('Search for an existing client'),
'#autocomplete_path' => 'searchclient/autocomplete',
);

$form['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Search'),
);
```

Then you need to make sure that 'searchclient/autocomplete' is registered as a valid menu path (hook_menu) like this for example:

```
/**
* @return array
* Implements hook_menu().
*/
function your_project_menu() {
$items = array();

$items['searchclient/autocomplete'] = array(
  'title' => t('AutoComp Menu'),
  'page callback' => 'your_project_search_client',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);

  return $items;
}
```

After this you need to create your page callback function that will actually return the content to the page:

```
function your_project_search_client($string) {

  $matches = array();

  // do what you want here

  drupal_json_output($matches);
  exit;
}
```

As some extra info:

-> $string is the entered search text in the form element
-> $matches holds the data to be returned to the screen.

More information on ajax callbacks can be found here:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax/7
https://www.drupal.org/node/2046693

Comment: Okay thanks very much for your answer. I still have a few questions though. Your code is different from the one you linked below. I don't completely understand what is happening. Where exactly is the ajax in this? In the documentation it says that you need an #ajax property. Also does the order in which the functions are written matter?

Answer (score 0):

@Codeling, two popular development debugging tools are [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel), and [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org) (often with [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/))

Now, for your question about the search results.  If you are new to Drupal it would probably be easier to go a non-ajax route at first.  There is a `form_state` option called [`rebuild`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7) that, when set to true, will allow you to show the results, keep the text in the search box, etc.

In your form `#submit` callback, set `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE`.  You could put your data in `$form_state['storage']` and then access it in your form builder, or even do the calculation in the builder itself.

Another option would be to look at the core [search](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.module/7) [module](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/search).  That implementation pulls the query it via `$_GET` instead, which would have less overhead as it passes around less data than the options mentioned above (assuming this approach covers your requirements).

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually already using devel. I think I'll try the ajax solution. It's just more elegant.